# Computing Floer homology of knots, going from graph to homology (following Manolescu's high-school level slides)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, knot-theory

Recently I came across the following expository slides of Ciprian Manolescu: [The unknotting problem: a journey from elementary to advanced mathematics](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ecm5/slides.html), talk for the high school students at the Romanian Master of Mathematics competition, Bucharest, 2012

They are a fantastic and indeed high-school level introduction to Floer homology for knots. It is truly a marvel to eat this sweet mathematical fruit, [borne](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/borne-vs-born-difference-usage-spelling) of great toil by many great mathematicians, conjured from the [Platonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonism) beyond, clarified and simplified, to be finally presented with such nice diagrams for the viewing pleasure of all humankind!

However, I do not understand the last step of going from the "a graph (of a chain complex) to homology", [pg. 23 of the slides](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ecm5/unknotting.pdf):
[image: graph to Floer homology Manolescu slides]

> **Questions:** What edges can we delete? When can we delete them? When can we delete vertices? Is that the only form of "zigzag" that can be replaced? I don't see a zigzag in the $3\times 3$ unknot example...